# React Canvas Container wrong size

Tags: reactjs, canvas, next.js, tailwind-css

It is a (NextJS) React application. I have a canvas inside a div container, each component is associated to a React Ref. My project also uses TailwindCSS. See the layout :

```
const Component = (): ReactElement => {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateCanvasSize = (
      container: HTMLDivElement,
      canvas: HTMLCanvasElement
    ) => {
      canvas.width = container.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      canvas.height = container.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    };

    // Updating canvas size
    if (canvasRef.current && containerRef.current) {
      canvasRef.current.style.width = '100%';
      canvasRef.current.style.height = '100%';

      updateCanvasSize(containerRef.current, canvasRef.current);
    }
  }, [canvasRef, containerRef]);

  return (
    <div className={'rounded-full w-80 h-80'} ref={containerRef}>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};
```

*This is not my real code, this is a short example of my component*

When rendering this component on a mobile phone, at the first page render, the canvas size isn't set properly. I have done some tests, when setting the canvas width and height, the retrieved container width and height are incorrect (offsetWidth & offsetHeight also) while the component has the correct size onscreen.
When reloading the page, the canvas size is set properly. I also tried to put a resize event listener, not working at all.

Comment: I'm having a hard time recreating your issue, could you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-react-ts-ze7iv)?

Comment: I have myself issues recreating the issue, that only works when built and hosted. Moreover, that work only on the first page load on iphone mobiles, when reloading the page, the bug disappear. You can check the website : lukaslaudrain.fr, repo is https://github.com/ctrl-plus-w/portfolio-v3.git on main branch